# Stripe connect - switching between test and live mode for the same client

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a platform that allow trainers to sell digital courses and enroll students into our platform to take them. Given that our app is a multi tenant one, we are using stripe connect to make request in the name of the trainers / handle payments.

The flow is:

A student sees a course he likes on the trainers website, is redirect to the payment page (custom platform page using stripe.js) and after payment is confirmed he receives acces to the course.

We would like to offer our customers (the trainers) the possibility to test the integration of their website with our platform on a course to course basis. Creating a course in test mode and then switching it to live mode if everything works fine.

Existing stripe customers are integrated to our platform using [stripe oauth](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-standard-accounts) (1).
Trainers who do not have a stripe account are onboarded with the recommended [stripe connect standard account creation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) (2).

My question is: after connecting accounts of type (1) or (2) to out stripe account, will making request using the platform stripe test key generate data into the test mode env for the trainer and using the stripe live key generate data into the live mode env?

Unfortunately I can't test this hypothesis as test accounts created from stripe onboarding do not have a live mode and I can't find any information regarding this in the stripe docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you connect a Stripe account to your platform using Oauth and your livemode platform client ID, then you should be able to make requests on behalf of that connected account in both live and test mode. Using the livemode key will make requests in livemode, and using the testmode key will make them in testmode.